# c++11 pugixml fpclassify() warning float-converstion from double to float may alter its value

Tags: c++, c++11, cross-compiling

I am using c++11 and using a (or the) pugixml c++ library. I am compiling the pugi files myself (1 .cpp file, and 2 .hpp files).

When using gcc on linux (ubuntu) it builds fine. When I build with a different x-compiler I get warnings (probably due to different architecture / integral sizes).... fair enough so far.

My problem is that I want to fix the warnings because I am using `-Werror` throughout my code / makefile and I have lots of warnings turned on.

The specific line of code in the pugixml library is as followins (its an ~12k line file):

```
#elif defined(fpclassify) && defined(FP_NAN)
    return fpclassify(value) == FP_NAN
#else
```

Where value is a `double`. The error I get is:

> conversion to 'float' from 'double' may alter its value [
>   -Werror=float-conversion ]

This seems to fix it: `return fpclassify(static_cast<float>(value)) == FP_NAN`

But what I can't see (other then because the compiler tells me) is what `fpclassify()` and `FP_NAN` are. I can see some documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/FP_categories) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify). It seems to show that there is a version of fpclassify for `float` and `double`.... so I am confused as to why there are warnings...

The x-compiler I am using is: `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc` version 5.2.0. which seems to support c++11.

I am looking for the reason why I get this warning. I can't really make a minimal example but if there is any further info that would be useful I can post it...

Comment: Looks like it should be fine.  If you run [this example code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify) do you get the same error?

Comment: @NathanOliver hmmm...yes that does seem to work (i.e. no error).... even more confused now

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.  Sorry, but I'm out of suggestions besides trying to make a [mcve]

Comment: @NathanOliver no worries, I made a sort of MMCV example... but it also does not show the problem!... must be some subtle thing within PUGIxml libs.